# How can I send HTTP request from service 1 to a service 2 in different containers in the same docker-compose file without specifying port of service 2

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I want to know how basket.api is able to send http request to the discount.grpc service without specifying the port

```
version: '3.4'

services:

   basket.api:
    container_name: basket.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings__ConnectionString=basketdb:6379"
      - "GrpcSettings:DiscountUrl=http://discount.grpc"
    depends_on:
      - basketdb
    ports:
      - "8001:80"

  discount.grpc:
    container_name: discount.grpc
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=Server=discountdb;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=33333;Password=33333;"
    depends_on:
      - discountdb
    ports
      - "8003:432"
```

I tried to change the port number of grpc to port other than 80 but I'm still able to send requests

Comment: The standard HTTP port number is 80.  If the destination service listens on port 80 inside its own container then you won't need to include a port number when calling between services.  Docker can't do this on its own, but if you do make the change in the application config you would also have to change the second `ports:` number in the very last line to match.

Comment: I know about the HTTP port 80 being default if no port is specified but as you can see in the compose file i have different port specified for grpc so i don't know why I'm able to send http request. I want to know how this possible even thought the port number is not 80.

Comment: Connections between containers don't use or require `ports:`.  If the process in the container is listening on 0.0.0.0:80 then you can make a plain-HTTP connection to it.

Comment: what happens if there are multiple ports in a container? then do i need to specify the port to identify the process

Comment: If the process inside the container is listening on multiple ports, a URL without a port like `http://discount.grpc` will reach port 80, and if you want a non-default port, you need to say it explicitly.  The is the same thing that would happen if you were running the process locally without Docker and were trying to access `localhost` URLs.